# WCF Stream Post with more than one parameter?

Tags: wcf

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.guruetech.com")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    UploadResult Upload(Stream itemStream); // succeeded!

    [OperationContract]
    UploadResult Upload(Stream itemStream, string theParameter); // failed!!!
}

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public UploadResult Upload(Stream itemStream)
    {
    }
    public UploadResult Upload(Stream itemStream, string theParameter) { } // failed!!!
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.  Can you form a question to help us understand what you need to accomplish?

Comment: How to pass multiple parameter in uritemplate with stream [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "assignHomework/sessionId={sessionId}/subjectId={subjectId}/classId={classId}/description={description}/?", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
       // [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/assignHomework",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        assignHomework[] assignHomework(string sessionId, string subjectId, string classId, string description, Stream image);

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

"Restrictions on Streamed Transfers

Using the streamed transfer mode causes the run time to enforce additional restrictions.

Operations that occur across a streamed transport can have a contract with **at most one input or output parameter**."